# International Student getting notarization in Canada. What ID do I use?

Tags: canada, passport, identification, notaries

I require a document notarized for my university here in Canada. I am an international student from the US. I currently have no Canadian ID (its still in progress), and am stuck in 14 day quarantine. The school will be starting soon however and before classes start I require to have submitted a form with notarization. I used https://www.notarize.ca/ to set up an appointment online. At one stage in eh form process it asked for an ID. One of the options was passport (it did not specify Canadian, nor did any of the other options).

My question: **Can I get a document notarized here in Canada using my American passport?**

Comment: I'm in the US, in Vermont (which is on the Canadian border). My impression is that notary regulations vary from one province to another; what province are you in. Also, online notarizations result in a pdf. If your university requires a paper document, that won't work. Finally online notarization services use financial records as one of the ways they ID you. They may not have access to US financial records, or as a young student, you may not have enough financial history.

Comment: @GerardAshton I'm in Ontario, could the pdf not be printed? And I do have enough financial history.

Comment: The security features of an electronic notarization are, of course, electronic. Once the document is printed, all these features are lost. It's easy to create a paper document that appears to be a paper copy of an electronically notarized document, but is actually a forgery. But your university MIGHT accept the paper copy anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been informed by the people over at https://www.notarize.ca that indeed, an American passport can be used.